How to run a task on windows 11 session opening ... but only once a month
I need a task to be performed once a month.
BUT
I cannot use the trigger "start the task every 1st of month at 8:00" (for example) because, maybe, the computer won't be turned on at 8:00 for each month. Maybe, on the first of a month, it won't be turned on at all.
So I guess the solution is to use the trigger "start when session is open" AND figure out how to limit to only a single one execution for a month lap.
But I don't know how to do that ... neither if it is possible.
I take any idea.
Thank you

Have you tried setting the trigger for a single monthly execution and then in the settings tab select 'Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed'?

I feel stupid ... I haven't seen this setting even though I went through all the tabs. Thnak you
